# Setting credentials programmatically for WebSphere 5.x Request Sender Binding BasicAuth Web Services client

Tags: java, web-services, websphere

I have a WebSphere 5.x WSAD-generated Web Service client that uses Dedicated Login Binding with BasicAuth authentication method. Using WSAD Web Services Client Editor tool I can set the required security settings and credentials, which are then propagated to ibm-webservicesclient-bnd/ext.xmi files. After deploying web application on server, it works properly. I am able to access these credentials on Websphere via Admin Console, by going to:

```
Enterprise Applications > *MyApp* > Web Module > *MyModule* > Web Services: Client Security Bindings > Request Sender Binding > Login Binding
```

However, I need to set these credentials programmatically, from Java logic. It seems the following calls are insufficient:

```
((javax.xml.rpc.Stub) service)._setProperty(javax.xml.rpc.Stub.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "user");
((javax.xml.rpc.Stub) service)._setProperty(javax.xml.rpc.Stub.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password");
```

Since I am getting the following response:

```
WSEC5075E: No security token found which satisfies any one of AuthMethods.
```

Is it possible to set the required credentials within generated client's Java logic?

If not, maybe this could be done by accessing the call in a low-level manner, possibly manually entering required security elements into SOAP message header?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by generating Axis Web Service client and implementing my own org.apache.axis.handlers.BasicHandler to modify the call. The handler is based on the WsseClientHandler from axis-wsse library.

The required logic is placed within the Stub file as follows:

```
    _call.setUsername("username");
    _call.setPassword("password");
    _call.setProperty(WsseClientHandler.PASSWORD_OPTION,
            WsseClientHandler.PASSWORD_CLEARTEXT);
    _call.setClientHandlers(new WsseClientHandler(), null);
```